# How to add QualifyingProperties in XML digitalSignature - Java

Tags: java

I am trying add digital signature on XML with ECDSA algorithm, where as I have added the digital sign on the XML.  But the xml should be signed with QualifyingProperties object tags,

The XML will have the multiple Transforms and Reference with it attribute id's,

When I tried with Xdes4j library am not able to add the multiple transforms and references ataObjectReference("").withTransform(new EnvelopedSignatureTransform()).withDataObjectFormat(
new DataObjectFormatProperty("text/xml"));

Hence i tried with the below approach with this i can add multiple transforms, Please advice how to add Object\QualifyingProperties  with this.

Thanks in advance,

Code:

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
        try {

            // Create XML document to insert the sign

            Document document = dbf.newDocumentBuilder()
                    .parse(new FileInputStream("..."));

            XMLSignatureFactory fac = XMLSignatureFactory.getInstance("DOM");

            //// Create and add Sign using DOM
            XMLSignature sig = new XMLSignature(document, "", XMLSignature.ALGO_ID_SIGNATURE_ECDSA_SHA256,
                    "http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#");

            NodeList signatureNodes = document.getElementsByTagName("ns4:SignatureInformation");

            Element elemToSign = (Element) signatureNodes.item(0);

            // Element root = document.getDocumentElement();
            elemToSign.appendChild(sig.getElement());

            // load the public and private key using alias
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("jks");
            keyStore.load(new FileInputStream("./conf/myCert.jks"), "123123".toCharArray());
            Key key = keyStore.getKey("1", "123123".toCharArray());

            // add the transforms and create reference
            Transforms transforms = new Transforms(document);

            // add the XPath
            XPathContainer xPath1 = new XPathContainer(document);
            xPath1.setXPathNamespaceContext("ext", Constants.NamespaceSpecNS);
            xPath1.setXPath("not(//ancestor-or-self::ext:UBLExtensions)");
            transforms.addTransform(Transforms.TRANSFORM_XPATH, xPath1.getElementPlusReturns());

            XPathContainer xpath2 = new XPathContainer(document);
            xpath2.setXPathNamespaceContext("ds", Constants.SignatureSpecNS);
            xpath2.setXPath("not(ancestor-or-self::ds:Signature)");
            transforms.addTransform(Transforms.TRANSFORM_XPATH, xpath2.getElementPlusReturns());

        
            transforms.addTransform(Transforms.TRANSFORM_C14N_EXCL_OMIT_COMMENTS);
            sig.addDocument("", transforms, "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1", "", "");

            // to add new reference
            Transforms transforms1 = new Transforms(document);

            sig.addDocument("", transforms1, "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1", "", "");

            // crate X509 certificate value;
            X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) keyStore.getCertificate("1");
            KeyInfoFactory kif = fac.getKeyInfoFactory();
            X509IssuerSerial issuerSerial = kif.newX509IssuerSerial(cert.getIssuerDN().getName(),
                    cert.getSerialNumber());
            List<Object> x509DataContent = new ArrayList<>();
            x509DataContent.add(issuerSerial);
            x509DataContent.add(cert);
            X509Data x509data = kif.newX509Data(x509DataContent);
            KeyValue keyValue = kif.newKeyValue(cert.getPublicKey());
            List<Object> keyInfoContent = new ArrayList<>();
            keyInfoContent.add(x509data);

            sig.addKeyInfo(cert);
            sig.sign(key);

            
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("....xml");
            TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer trans = tf.newTransformer();
            trans.transform(new DOMSource(document), new StreamResult(os));


XML OUPUT:

    <ns4:SignatureInformation>
                        <ns4:ID>urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:signature:1</ns4:ID>
                        <ns4:ReferencedSignatureID>urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:signature:Invoice</ns4:ReferencedSignatureID>
                        <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                            <ds:SignedInfo>
                                <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                                <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#ecdsa-sha256"/>
                                <ds:Reference Id="invoiceSignedData" Type="" URI="">
                                    <ds:Transforms>
                                        ....
                                    </ds:Transforms>
                                    <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                                    <ds:DigestValue>QPwr0wNnXvvpwiTl3zfHhtkfGV0=</ds:DigestValue>
                                </ds:Reference>
                        
                            </ds:SignedInfo>
                            <ds:SignatureValue>AQm68Cmc50lzcUyYZbSGYq3rXpQOLfSOnCfpzKMq5y9oBSt2D+cfj2SMHzx+rSrf235XCEWAMUeF&#13; MvVQSXSSjuz8Acyzb8R8pSWFWYr2ktS0UDpwK/mkUOy+CxHXzSO/KuJZISkBCvbmKbOayr5rNqXb&#13; eaO7xzIm09vZTq5E4kwlZvRH</ds:SignatureValue>
                            <ds:KeyInfo>
                                <ds:X509Data>
                                    <ds:X509Certificate>MIICyDCCAiqgAwIBAgIJAIpwID4vNGePMAoGCCqGSM49BAMCMH0xCzAJBgNVBAYTAklOMQswCQYD&#13; VQQIDAJUTjEOMAwGA1UEBwwFS0FSVVIxDzANBgNVBAoMBlNBVFVSTjEMMAoGA1UECwwDVURUMQ8w&#13; DQYDVQQDDAZBTUFMQUsxITAfBgkqhkiG9w0BCQEWEmplZ2FkZWVwQGdtYWlsLmNvbTAeFw0yMTA5&#13; MjMxNTI3NTNaFw0yMjA5MTgxNTI3NTNaMH0xCzAJBgNVBAYTAklOMQswCQYDVQQIDAJUTjEOMAwG&#13; A1UEBwwFS0FSVVIxDzANBgNVBAoMBlNBVFVSTjEMMAoGA1UECwwDVURUMQ8wDQYDVQQDDAZBTUFM&#13; QUsxITAfBgkqhkiG9w0BCQEWEmplZ2FkZWVwQGdtYWlsLmNvbTCBmzAQBgcqhkjOPQIBBgUrgQQA&#13; IwOBhgAEASe9LFSDXw2zJoiKef+puJEdpNpZW3fF0RVwyobDjBLx/G8ETmy6eRR1yaYPGuRSzOAh&#13; cKIXhf9KLpJ7x154wgagALokY2MIyvdvpgjBX54q4JMlBNhXY8QQ3fnX+FRL0fN9XXCuZJL2+aa0&#13; oFEPvPEeS2XYLWseautV3EdB/HZLGZr4o1AwTjAdBgNVHQ4EFgQU+DkDNsFyn8Wtfp9L6+hvNcvx&#13; hLEwHwYDVR0jBBgwFoAU+DkDNsFyn8Wtfp9L6+hvNcvxhLEwDAYDVR0TBAUwAwEB/zAKBggqhkjO&#13; PQQDAgOBiwAwgYcCQgEQVf1ez28GRdNhPVpNeVeP38pP2BLKd31iu6ZAJO856WXWdyOrZnrKULqn&#13; aElT1unWk/zQ3AI+nZMl8mfRRPv16gJBcPWWcPJxyf05H0g2bQ4f+KmwyvAsBTGBdnrUUapfwgN/&#13; G2p8Ak0DVXZH9CDOSYJ3wf7hcZZbEZznUSLRHBCACj8=</ds:X509Certificate>
                                </ds:X509Data>
                            </ds:KeyInfo>
                        </ds:Signature>
                    </ns4:SignatureInformation>

Expectation is with the below Object TAG

    <ds:Object>
                                <xades:QualifyingProperties xmlns:xades="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#" xmlns:xades141="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.4.1#" Target="#xmldsig-bda769b6-df2c-41cc-94bf-2264eabd6387">
                                    <xades:SignedProperties Id="xmldsig-bda769b6-df2c-41cc-94bf-2264eabd6387-signedprops">
                                        <xades:SignedSignatureProperties>
                                            <xades:SigningTime>2021-09-30T09:00:23.955+05:30</xades:SigningTime>
                                            <xades:SigningCertificate>
                                                <xades:Cert>
                                                    <xades:CertDigest>
                                                        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                                                        <ds:DigestValue>ftD6/IyekRICncMA1X8ijPVX7iLJnIBfOLAVy507Vi8=</ds:DigestValue>
                                                    </xades:CertDigest>
                                                    <xades:IssuerSerial>...                                                 
                                                    </xades:IssuerSerial>
                                                </xades:Cert>
                                            </xades:SigningCertificate>
                                        </xades:SignedSignatureProperties>
                                        <xades:SignedDataObjectProperties>
                                            <xades:DataObjectFormat ObjectReference="#xmldsig-bda769b6-df2c-41cc-94bf-2264eabd6387-ref0">
                                                <xades:MimeType>text/xml</xades:MimeType>
                                            </xades:DataObjectFormat>
                                        </xades:SignedDataObjectProperties>
                                    </xades:SignedProperties>
                                </xades:QualifyingProperties>
                            </ds:Object>


Thanks in advance.
```